# issue while understanding the map and input function python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to take a list from user input using below code

```
n=int(input())
list1=[]
for i in range(0,n):
   ele=list(map(int,input()))
   list1.append(ele)
print(list1)
```

as per my understanding for below input 3 23 23 33
this should give me [23,23,33], however I am getting [[2,3],[2,3],[3,3]]
can anyone please help understanding the flow and working of the map and list function and what I am missing.

Comment: Did you read the docs for `map()`? What do you think it will do, given that the `input()` will return `str`, i.e. iterable? it will apply `int()` to whole input or to each char?

Comment: Is the input really a single line - 3 23 23 33 or is it split over 2 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) doc described:

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

The mistakes as follows:

1. `input()` function get a `string` from your console standard input. And, `string` is an iterable type! So, `list(map(int, "23"))` will return a `[2,3]` list.
2. `list1.append(list2)` will get a nested list like `[[2,3]]`.

To get your wished result, you may change `ele=list(map(int,input()))` to `ele=int(input())`.

Answer (score 1):

This would get what you want:

```py
n = int(input())
list1 = [
    int(input()) for _ in range(n)
]
print(list1)
```

Comment: This will produce desired result, but it does not explain (to OP)  what is the problem with their code

Comment: According to the question the input is **3 23 23 33** - i.e., a single line. Therefore this answer will not work. Furthermore it would require n+1 discrete input Ines

Answer (score 0):

thanks! understand the working now as the below
input() function get a string from your console standard input. And, the string is an iterable type! So, list(map(int, "23")) will return a [2,3] list.